# I am getting "Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version."

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, java-8, aws-codepipeline

I am getting **Action execution failed
Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version. Failed to deploy application. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0a956bec0b978125a'. Aborting the operation. [Instance: i-0a956bec0b978125a] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error.. Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.**  error while deploying via code pipeline.

I have no idea why this error occurring. My application is a legacy spring 1.5.9 application built on java 8.

My buildspec.yml:

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto8
  build:
    commands:
      - java -version
      - mvn clean install
artifacts:
  files:
    - target/d_campus.jar
```

Its about 4 hours.....I am stucked. Please help

Comment: Have you fixed this error ? I got same error.

Comment: Inferring from the reference to `eb-engine.log`, you are deploying to Elastic Beanstalk, right? Unfortunately, EB's error messages are pretty useless at times. Check your logs. It could be misconfiguration at the application level or the EB enviornment level.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-logging.html

Comment: @M123456 yes fortunately I have. This thing -" <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>" - at pom.xml was causing the error. After deleting it error got resolved.

Comment: @AmimulEhsanRahi Ok... I didn't add that. Do you have any idea what other reasons could be for that error?